# distribution r studio

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

About 12% of males are colorblind. A researcher needs three colorblind men for an experiment and begins checking potential subjects. What is the probability that she finds exactly 3 or 4 men in the first 7 trials she examines? The average number of colorblind men out of sample size of 7 is equal to 0,84.

if sample zize = 7, and mean = 0,84 => P (x = 3 or 4) equals 2/7 = 0.2857

but why we need mean? and in r studio is binomial probability and i should use pbinom? if im right could u please check

pbinom (3:4, 7, 2/7)
[1] 0.8917264 0.9767250

Comment: The question asks for a single number: "the probability that..."  Your output has two numbers!

Comment: In R, use PDF and add: `sum(dbinom(3:4. 7, .12))` to get $0.04121543.$ Alternatively, use CDF and subtract: `pbinom(4, 7, .12) - pbinom(2, 7, .12)` to get
$0.04121543.$